# Unix Interpreter wrapper that can fit into shebang

Tags: python, unix, shebang

the python executable is "/path/A/B/python". But unfortunately I need to source a file and export some environmental variables to make that executable runnable.

So I want to define my own "interpreter", say `/home/name/mypython`

```
#!/bin/bash 
source something
/path/A/B/python
```

and include above script in the shebang of a python file

```
#!/home/name/mypython

## rest of the python script
```

but unfortunately it doesn't work. it just brings me to a python shell without doing anything. what else should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Assume:

- python-script: path/to/my_script.py
- path to a python_executable: /path/A/B/python
- a shell script: /home/name/mypython.sh

The way you set it up. the shebang in my_script.py calls mypython.sh which executes the commands of sourcing and than calls a python interpreter with no arguments resulting in the python shell.

add the path of my_script.py to  mypython.sh, this way the shebang in my_script.py is ignored

```
#!/bin/bash 
source something
/path/A/B/python path/to/my_script.py
```

there is a really good thread how the shebang and python works:
[Why do people write the #!/usr/bin/env python shebang on the first line of a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-the-usr-bin-env-python-shebang-on-the-first-line-of-a-pyt)